# Why can't I import a world?

Tags: terraria

I'm trying to move my world from my Linux install to my Windows install, and it's not working. I delete the "My Games/Terraria" folder from Windows, and copy over the one from Linux, but when I start up Terraria on Windows and load the world, it's still the old one. The one I deleted. I have no idea how this is happening.

Comment: While I don't have enough information to give a true answer I am going to suggest some more information you could give that would help others to answer. Where did this Terraria come from? For example, the Steam and GOG versions can, in some circumstances, use different save folders from each other (it has to do with the steam cloud and I have GOG so I am not familiar with it all). Also you should try just adding the new world and savegame files alongside the old ones. Keep backups, of course, but it sounds like you are already doing that.

Comment: They're both the Steam version. The problem with adding the new world alongside the old one is that they're both the same world. I started it on Windows, then when the Linux client was released I copied it from my Windows install to my Linux install, and when I started having issues with the Linux client I tried to copy it back to Windows.

Comment: That does complicate things a bit. I myself have run it under WINE in linux. When I moved my saves around I just moved the .wld and .plr files around. Also depending on the settings steam may be backing up your world to the cloud or something (Not having the steam version I am not familiar with its eccentricities).

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the problem. At some point in the beta, the save location was moved from `~/My Games/Terraria` to `~/.local/share/Terraria`. I was still trying to copy from the My Games folder, not realizing those were old files.

Comment: This tripped me up too. Especially because it leaves the old files in `~/My Games`. Very annoying. Glad you found it though. I was experiencing this exact issue where it wouldn't see any maps I added. I was baffled thinking somehow the map files must be different for Mac, but the more I thought about it that just seemed silly and arbitrary since the entire game is just running in a wrapper. Then I figured this out and facepalmed, lol.

Answer (score 0):

The world is most likely in the cloud. When you move a world or a character to cloud in the Terraria interface, is literally moving it, not making a copy, your world resides in the cloud, and it takes precedence over anything local.

Now you're saying that when creating new worlds, they're both the same; so there might be a problem with your worlds being automatically moved to cloud once created.

You can disable the cloud storage per world, by clicking on the little cloud icon alongside each world and character, or you can disable cloud storage globally for the game by going into the game properties from steam and disable the cloud storage. Also if you want, you can re-enable it once your worlds are where they're supposed to be.

Comment: None of the worlds say they're stored in the cloud, and they're all physically present as files on the computer.

Comment: as .world, or as .world.bak ?

Comment: As .world, and their folder